# How to prove this sum diverges?

Tags: calculus, summation

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ((n+1)^{(1/3)}-(n-1)^{(1/3)})^\alpha$

I am aware that this sum diverges by the comparison test. However, I can't find another sum for the test.

Thank you.

Comment: $$a-b=(a^3-b^3)/(a^2+ab+b^2).$$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I thought about that too but couldn't find a way to use it to solve the problem.

Comment: Try a little harder. What's $a$ and what's $b$ ?

Answer (score 0):

We have

$(1\pm\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{3}}=1\pm \frac{1}{3n}(1+\epsilon(n))$

thus

$$u_n\sim (n^{\frac{1}{3}}\frac{2}{3n})^\alpha$$

so it converges if $\alpha>\frac{3}{2}$.